# Google Ads - Is there a way to create a report which shows Search Queries by Location?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-ads-360

I have a campaign which has location targeting to the entire radius of my city. It has collected data from various areas within the city. Now my client wants to open a new location in a specific location within the city and would like to know what data we have collected for that area (postal code).

I've done some light research and i've read that google considers this a PII issue, thus will not simply expose reports like this, but i'm also hearing from others there are ways to do just custom. Im just wondering if this functionality is available out the box in Google Ads or Google Analytics, or if there is an easy way to do this without coding. I've tried compiling reports based on conversion by location but cannot get search query information to see what the users in that location are searching.

Comment: do you gather zip codes or geo data from users clicking your ads? if not there is no way to show them. If you gather them, so the way to display them depends on the gathering kind.

Comment: By default in Google Ads, there is a User Location Report, which shows conversions, impressions or clicks by Postal code. These postal codes are generic in a sense they encapulate a certain area of the city.  For example, in Vancouver, BC, Canada, the postal code V6B would represent a region in the downtown area. Now we have conversions from a particular postcode of the city, but I can't see what the search queries were, or what the keywords were which triggered the conversion from that postal code area. I Just need to bridge the gap

Comment: there should be a way to tinker a kind of custom report, where you have possibility to break down any dimension/metric you want (and have). Look into custom reports. I'm not a big profi in GA, but i'm pretty sure, that on the level of Ads such insights `should` be possible (because you actually paid for them).

Comment: You can't use location with keywords, Google won't allow it, just tried several custom report combinations, i think it's pretty clear it's a PII issue, and the only way to get this data is to target a specific area and compile the information manually.